# Why is this function primitive recursive?

Tags: computability, primitive-recursion

Let $f:\mathbb{N}^{p+1} \to \mathbb{N}$ a primitive recursive function and $g:\mathbb{N}^{p+1} \to \mathbb{N}$ the bounded sum defined by : $g(\bar{a},x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^x f(\bar a , i)$.

To show that $g$ is  a primitive recursive function we want to show that $g$ is closed under the primitive recursion :

$g(\bar a, 0)= f(\bar a ,0)= k(\bar a)$ where $k$ is a primitive recursive function because of $f$.

$g(\bar a, x+1) = g(\bar a , x) + f(\bar a,x+1)$.

But if we want to find explicitly a recursive primitive function $h$ such that : $g(\bar a, x+1) = h(\bar a, x ,g(\bar a, x))$ which $h$ should we take ?

I mean how can we make appear $f(\bar a , x+1)$ in $h$ ? As $f$ is primitive recursive we can write : $f(\bar a , x+1)= h'(\bar a, x, f(\bar a, x))$ hence $g(\bar a, x+1) = g(\bar a , x) + h'(\bar a, x, f(\bar a, x))$ but then I am stuck...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you basically have the answer. You just have to solve the equation h(a, x, g(a, x)) = g(a, x) + f(a, x + 1). So what is h(a, x, r)? We want to find an expression that involves r that makes h(a, x, g(a, x)) = g(a, x) + f(a, x + 1). We see that g(a, x) appears in the place of r and appears on the right hand side as well. So what happens if we sub g(a, x) for r on both sides?

Comment: @Jake Ok so we'll get $h(\bar{a},x,r)= r + f(\bar{a},x+1)= \text{add}(\pi^{n+2}_{n+2} h(\bar a,x,r),f(\bar a, x+1))$ ? This function is primitive recursive in case... Why do we make appear an $r$ ?